# JNI native method not found

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I've got a package called com.example.remote in that package I have a Remote.java file with

```
public native static void send_feedback(String feedback);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("com_example_remote_Remote");
}
```

then in my com_example_remote_Remote.c file I got this method:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_remote_Remote_send_feedback(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring feedback)
```

Everything compiles. But when I do a call to the java function the program stops working and gives me:

```
12-19 12:21:31.183: E/AndroidRuntime(3196): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 12:21:31.183: E/AndroidRuntime(3196): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.example.remote.Remote.send_feedback:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
12-19 12:21:31.183: E/AndroidRuntime(3196):     at com.example.remote.Remote.send_feedback(Native Method)
```

I think my syntax is conform the rules of JNI. I deleted the obj map once I thought maybe it would solve the problem. I rebuild the project and still gives me that error.

EDIT:

changed the name to sendFeedback and now I get this error:

```
12-19 12:49:26.335: A/libc(3280): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000cd0 (code=0), thread 3280 (.example.remote)
```

Comment: do you have libcom_example_remote_Remote.so in libs/ABINAME folders(where ABINAME is fx armabi, x86,...)? are you using emulator with intel CPU/ABI? if so you hav to compile your native lib to x86, too

Comment: Remove underscore from your function name or escape it with '_1'

Comment: I've got a .so file in the armeabi folder. I'm using a nexus s to test this.

Answer (score 1):

Add `extern "C"` in native method definition. i.e.

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_remote_Remote_send_feedback(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring feedback){.......}
```

Or

If possible change MethodName in declaration and definition (in java file and .c file) because `_` may be problem in method name. i.e.

```
public native static void sendFeedback(String feedback);


extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_remote_Remote_sendFeedback(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring feedback)
{
....
}
```

you may find a sample [here](http://www.jayway.com/2011/10/13/getting-started-with-android-ndk/)

Comment: I've changed the name to sendFeedback now the app just closes with this error msg: 12-19 12:49:26.335: A/libc(3280): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000cd0 (code=0), thread 3280 (.example.remote). I also got a .h file do I need to recreate him?

Comment: @user1480139 may be there is some error in method body's code. Fix that and then recompile it. It will again generate a .so file in `obj -> armeabi' folder

Comment: Apparently there is a error in the body of the function even thought it compiled. Thanks. But is it necessary to recreate the header? I tried with javah -jni ClassName in the bin/classes folder but javah always complains about "could nog find class file for ..."

Comment: @user1480139 I think its not necessary, but you can recreate.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in the folder where the .class files are and I run the command javah com.example.remote.Remote and I get as output that he doesn't find the classfile. Every post I found on stackoverflow gives me that syntax. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the name to sendFeedback so it's without the underscore. Also there was an error in the method what doesn't matter for this answer.